# ¿Cómo eliminar el espaciado abajo de mi H3?

Tags: html, css

Que tal buenas tardes a todos.

Al momento de hacer

> *position: relative*

a mi `H3` y asignarle

> bottom: 90px;

se me genera un espacio abajo de mi `h3` y se me genera la barra de `scroll` y no encuentro la manera de quitar el espaciado.

A continuación mi código:

```css
body {
  background-image: url("https://wallimpex.com/file/load/225/2800x2100-6099365-wood-wallpapers-hd.jpg");
  margin: 0;
}

.img-pizza img {
  width: 500px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px;
  padding-top: 40px;
}

.linea {
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-right: 40px;
}

p {
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: justify;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  color: black;
}

a {
  padding: 25px;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.container-recet {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}

.life-dit span {
  margin: 0;
}

h2 {
  color: white;
  text-align: end;
  margin: 0;
  margin-right: 160px;
  font-size: 30px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 70px;
}

h3 {
  color: white;
  text-align: end;
  font-size: 100px;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 90px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Examen prueba</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylo.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="main-container">
    <div class="img-pizza">
      <img src="https://paralelo32-4hiq9fbm.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/pizza-capresse-sin-sal.jpg" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="container-recet">
      <h1>
        Receta para pizza
      </h1>
      <div class="linea">
      </div>
      <p> <strong>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, elit consectefer adiplong Valuptate, por asi decirlo esta obligado
        por un gran dolor que ha condenado? Está unido a un gran allio de mis labores, que tuve desde el momento
        de la falla, el sabio vino deken.Noque, o bien, de toda, su vision stands sabias que añoran.
        </strong>
      </p>
      <a href="#">Ver la receta completa</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h2>VIDA</h2>
  <h3>MRR</h3>
</body>

</html>


[![El pequeño scroll][1]][1]
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBJjU.png

Comment: Gracias ivan, como haces para colocar esos botones?

Comment: Sugeriria que primero modifiques un poco el codigo en la pregunta; el `h3` es de color blanco y por ende no se ve en ejemplo; ademas podrias explicar un poco mas el problema? No estoy muy claro

Comment: Para agregar eso debes hacer click en la opcion de "fragmento JS/HTML/CSS"; y ahi escribes tu codigo en las secciones correspondientes; es el boton que se encuentra al lado derecho del que usas para incluir imagenes; se mira como una hoja de papel con los simbolos `<>`

Comment: En un momento corrijo los fondos que utilice, los tomare online para que se reflejen.

Comment: Ivan, ya puedes ver la pagina con los fondos y la imagen completa.

Comment: Mi problema es que se genera scroll abajo de el texto VIDA MRR y solo quiero que la página acabe hasta ahí y que no se genere la barra de scroll.

Comment: Por lo que veo solo se genera el scroll si ya no hay mas espacio disponible; probandolo aqui al expandir la pantalla de tu ejemplo, se mira bien, sin barra de scroll

Comment: Hmmm que raro, yo al tenerla completa se me genera un ligero scroll.

Comment: Agrega una imagen de tu pantalla si es posible

Comment: Listo, hasta el final se puso como un link.

Comment: A mi no me ocurre eso que cuentas, pero una forma sencilla de arreglarlo, es insepeccionar el elemento que tenga la barra que quieres eliminar y colocarle un overflow: none;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bien, creo que entiendo lo que sucede, pero ten en cuenta que ese comportamiento es normal, y dependiendo de lo que quieres tener; de la funcion que tienen esos titulos al final, puedes necesitar hacer diferentes cambios.

Tus dos titulos (`h2` y `h3`) tienen la propiedad `position: relative`; esto hace que puedas moverlos cierta distancia tomando como referencia su posicion inicial; lo que sucede es que esto no "quita" el elemento de donde estaba originalmente antes de moverlo, por tanto el espacio que ocupa sigue estando ahi, simplemente esta vacio. Ya que tu pantalla al parecer no es lo suficientemente grande, el espacio del `h3` hace que aparezca un scroll.

Una opcion que tienes para evitarlo es usar `position: absolute`, esto hace que en vez de mover el elemento respecto a su posicion original, lo muevas con referencia al padre que lo contiene; de esta forma el espacio que ocupaba originalmente (y que esta vacio cuando usas `position: relavtive` desparece por completo, pero el comportamiento del elemento cambia un poco, mira el ejemplo.

```css
body {
  background-image: url("https://wallimpex.com/file/load/225/2800x2100-6099365-wood-wallpapers-hd.jpg");
  margin: 0;
}

.img-pizza img {
  width: 500px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px;
  padding-top: 40px;
}

.linea {
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-right: 40px;
}

p {
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: justify;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  color: black;
}

a {
  padding: 25px;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.container-recet {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}

.life-dit span {
  margin: 0;
}

h2 {
  color: white;
  text-align: end;
  margin: 0;
  margin-right: 160px;
  font-size: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0;
}

h3 {
  color: white;
  text-align: end;
  font-size: 100px;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Examen prueba</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylo.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="main-container">
    <div class="img-pizza">
      <img src="https://paralelo32-4hiq9fbm.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/pizza-capresse-sin-sal.jpg" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="container-recet">
      <h1>
        Receta para pizza
      </h1>
      <div class="linea">
      </div>
      <p> <strong>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, elit consectefer adiplong Valuptate, por asi decirlo esta obligado
        por un gran dolor que ha condenado? Está unido a un gran allio de mis labores, que tuve desde el momento
        de la falla, el sabio vino deken.Noque, o bien, de toda, su vision stands sabias que añoran.
        </strong>
      </p>
      <a href="#">Ver la receta completa</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h2>VIDA</h2>
  <h3>MRR</h3>
</body>

</html>
```

Sin embargo creo que si solo necesitas que termine hasta donde estan los titulos no necesitas posicionarlos, solo se ubicaran despues de la tarjeta; y si no hay espacio disponible pues la barra de scroll aparecera, como es de esperarse.

```css
body {
  background-image: url("https://wallimpex.com/file/load/225/2800x2100-6099365-wood-wallpapers-hd.jpg");
  margin: 0;
}

.img-pizza img {
  width: 500px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px;
  padding-top: 40px;
}

.linea {
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-right: 40px;
}

p {
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: justify;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  color: black;
}

a {
  padding: 25px;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.container-recet {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}

.life-dit span {
  margin: 0;
}

h2 {
  color: white;
  text-align: end;
  margin: 0;
  margin-right: 160px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

h3 {
  color: white;
  text-align: end;
  font-size: 100px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Examen prueba</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylo.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="main-container">
    <div class="img-pizza">
      <img src="https://paralelo32-4hiq9fbm.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/pizza-capresse-sin-sal.jpg" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="container-recet">
      <h1>
        Receta para pizza
      </h1>
      <div class="linea">
      </div>
      <p> <strong>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, elit consectefer adiplong Valuptate, por asi decirlo esta obligado
        por un gran dolor que ha condenado? Está unido a un gran allio de mis labores, que tuve desde el momento
        de la falla, el sabio vino deken.Noque, o bien, de toda, su vision stands sabias que añoran.
        </strong>
      </p>
      <a href="#">Ver la receta completa</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h2>VIDA</h2>
  <h3>MRR</h3>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Si eso era, que tonto soy pero pues apenas estoy aprendiendo CSS, muchas gracias Ivan por tomarte el tiempo de ayudarme :D

Comment: No hay problema, con el tiempo lo vas a dominar

Comment: Claro, gracias bro :D